# Error when creating pairwise scatter plots from first 5 genes in ALL dataset: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r

I'm working with the ALL dataset in R and trying to create a pairwise scatterplot with the first 5 genes. Here is my code:

```
data(ALL, library = ALL)
x <- exprs(ALL)[1:5,]
par(mfrow=c(5,5))
pairs(x)
```

I get this error: **Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large**

I have read in other posts that adjusting the size of my window might work, but had no luck.

Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
    > head(x)
             01005    01010    03002    04006    04007    04008    04010    04016    06002    08001    08011    08012    08018
1000_at   7.597323 7.479445 7.567593 7.384684 7.905312 7.065914 7.474537 7.536119 7.183331 7.735545 7.591498 7.824284 7.231814
1001_at   5.046194 4.932537 4.799294 4.922627 4.844565 5.147762 5.122518 5.016132 5.288943 4.633217 4.583148 4.685951 5.059300
1002_f_at 3.900466 4.208155 3.886169 4.206798 3.416923 3.945869 4.150506 3.576360 3.900935 3.630190 3.609112 3.902139 3.804705
1003_s_at 5.903856 6.169024 5.860459 6.116890 5.687997 6.208061 6.292713 5.665991 5.842326 5.875375 5.733157 5.762857 5.770914
1004_at   5.925260 5.912780 5.893209 6.170245 5.615210 5.923487 6.046607 5.738218 5.994515 5.748350 5.922568 5.679899 6.044520
```

Comment: Try shrinking the margins when you call `par`. You can set this in inches (e.g. `par(mfrow = c(5, 5), mai = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))`), or you can set the number of lines of text (e.g. `par(mfrow = c(5, 5), mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))`). Try setting the margins very small at first (your axis annotations and labels may be clipped), and then slowly expand. Read the help for `par` for details.

Comment: I am still unable to get any plots no matter how I modify the margin settings. Is there an issue with structure of my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t() fixed my problem

exprs(ALL)[1:5,] 
This gave me 5 rows and 128 columns which was making my pairwise scatter plot **gigantic**.

t(exprs(ALL)[1:5,]) transposed the rows and columns (i.e. swapped the rows and columns) so that I had 128 rows and 5 columns.